# Abnormalities of Model training - Various result on different time with same parameter and hyperparamerter

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Sounds like a silly question but feel really annoying. During model training, why it's so weird sometimes as to get different output or result or more specifically **accuracy** or **validation accuracy** when nothing changes in the model parameter?

Let's say we build a model name **`A`**. We train it and get the result and that's something like **acc = 60** and **val_acc = 70**. Ok fine.

Now, train that same model another time (without closing the environment) and this time we get **acc = 40** and **val_acc = 20** ....? I mean, why? Nothing changes inside the model, no `parameter` no `hyperparameter`, nothing at all. Then why it shows this weirdness.

Comment: You need to describe the model you are training and how you are training it. You tagged your question "deep-learning" so I'm guessing there are some random processes involved in initialization but without knowing specifics of what you are doing (type of model, number of training epochs, etc.) it is hard to give a specific answer.

Comment: This is because of random weight initialization, it is not weird at all.

Comment: @bogatron this will be too big if I include everything.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro `glorot_uniform` used as a kernel initializer. And by the way, everything back to normal, when I re-run the whole program from the beginning without exiting the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set random seeds of your environment. Then the program should be reproducable. An example on how this is done in keras is shown here(https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/), but this exists for every other library as well.